# Citrix XenApp qfarm displays no servers, load shows 100

Tags: windows-server-2008, citrix, xenapp

I had a Citrix XenApp 6.5 sever running smoothly in a very simple domain (one DC, one XenApp server) until the XenApp server had to be restarted recently. After it came back, applications can no longer be launched from a Receiver.

In the Event logs I can see:

```
A usable server cannot be found on which to launch the application. 

The Citrix servers reported that they are too busy to provide access to the selected resource. This message was reported from the XML Service at address ...
```

Running `qfarm` displays no servers. Running `qfarm /load` shows my one server (which is local to where `qfarm` is being executed) at 100 load. I have checked the license server and there are no errors

**Edit:** Executing

```
net stop imaservice
net start imaservice
```

Allowed the server to show up under `qfarm`, but load was initially at 10000. It eventually went back down to 100, and applications were able to be launched. The issue appears to be connected then to the server showing up there, and I have a hunch that it's network/DNS related as `qfarm /addr HOSTNAME` was not returning an IP previously, but is now. This was also reflected in AppCenter